# PreferenceEditText to string

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences

So I have EditText in my Preferences and i want to get the text it and use it as String.Then i want to use that string everytime when my button is clicked and it will set my another EditText text to the string from Preference. Codes :

```
<EditTextPreference android:title="Uredi Text"
    android:key="ime"
    android:summary="ime pjesme"
    />
```

Java code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
    String b1t = preferences.getString("ime", "DEFAULT");
 et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
//Button Click
public void button(View view) {
        et1.setText(b1t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the developer docs, you can just use `edittextpreference.getText().toString()`

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

Comment: et1.setText(preferences.getString("ime", "something")); Crashes my application.. javal.ang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you sure that you can put two strings into the setText() method? What happens if you only put one in?

Comment: preferences.getString needs string key and string def value.. preferences.getstring(String Key, String defValue);

Comment: I get java.lang.NullPointerException error and this one 11-16 22:51:56.209: E/AndroidRuntime(14703): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your error is so I'll just give you my code for doing this.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext();

         String string = sharedPreferences
                .getString("key", "default");
```

And in my preferences

```
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="default"
        android:key="key"
        android:summary="I'm a summary"
        android:title="I'm a title" />
```

For the onCLick method to modify the edit text

```
  EditText editText = (EditText) 
        findViewById(R.id.editText);

  editText.setText(String.valueOf(string));
```

This code works. If your application still crashes then your issue is either with your onClick event or something else. I personally prefer onClickListeners for buttons.

Heres the code for an onClickListener.

```
 Button button = (Button)
      findViewById(R.id.button);

 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {

          //Do some awesome stuff

     }
 });
```

Comment: sharedPreferences.getString("ime", "default"); always gets string "default"

Comment: What this code (sharedPreferences.getString("ime", "default");) does it is looks for a key named "ime" in your shared preferences. If it cannot find a match it uses a default test named "default" in this example. Change the name "default" to "test". If your value comes up with "test" this time then your problem is saving the preference not retrieving it.

Answer (score 1):

> **edit:** John posted his answer before mine, and his answer reflects most use cases, such as in a standard `Activity`. My answer is directed solely at the use of a `PreferenceActivity`.

Here's how you can add `Preference`s with defaults based on another `Preference` within a `PreferenceActivity`. Sorry if there are any errors, I'm typing on my phone.

Your `XML`-defined `Preference`s will have their values saved to SharedPreferences automatically, but code-created `Preference`s will need to be saved/persisted manually.

`PreferenceActivity`'s `onConfigurationChange()` *usually* saves the state of code-created preferences (nested PreferenceScreens are a bit strange.)

And, of course, you'll want to do null checks (omitted to save my thumbs.)

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="Preferences"
    android:key="root">
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Default Pref Text"
        android:key="ime"
        android:summary="ime pjesme"
    />
    <Preference android:title="Click to add a preference."
        android:key="add"
        android:summary=""
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**MyActivity.class**

```
public class MyActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle inState) {
        super.onCreate(inState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getPreferenceScreen.findPreference(PREFERENCE_BUTTON).
          setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnNewPrefClickListener());
    }
    private class OnNewPrefClickListener implements OnPreferenceClickListener {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            PreferenceScreen rootScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
            EditTextPreference defaultPref = 
                      (EditTextPreference)rootScreen.findPreference("ime");
            String defaultText = defaultPref.getText();
            EditTextPreference newPref = new EditTextPreference(getApplicationContext());
            newPref.setText(defaultText);
            rootScreen.addPreference(newPref);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```